# Почему один код выполняется асинхронно, второй синхронно?

Tags: foreach, promise, асинхронность, callback

Если внутри ф-н запустить еще один callback - то данный код асинхронный, потому что нам нужно дождаться ответа, от внутренней ф-н

***Здесь вернет undefined***
[image]

***Здесь вернет уже User***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос вот в чем

> ***Почему в reduce все выполняется синхронно и возвращаются значение в массиве, а не undefined ?***
> **Или здесь нет ничего асинхронного?
> Пожалуйста объясните.**
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что reduce это синхронный метод

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что операции метода выполняются синхронно. Хотя можете попробовать поставить settimeout внутри метода и посмотреть, что получится

Comment: Метод Firebase так же выполняется синхронно, но если не использовать промис возвращается undefined

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю, мы ведь acc прикидываем во внутренний callback который там че то делает, мы его не возвращаем от туда, после мы возвращаем acc и там лежат значения, я думал там будут лежать undefined, или я че то не так понимаю